# Validate current_user if it is already in DB

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I can't get validation error to be displayed, only IntegrityError from SQLAlchemy

*(sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: Booking.username).*

I have two tables in DB, one is a list of registered users, another one is a list of logged in users where they can book time thru FlaskForm with RadioFields. I think I have mistake in this function **def validate_booking (self)**

I need to check if the current_user already booked time then he cannot do another booking

> I moved validation function into LoginForm instead and this seems to
> be working. It validates before the user jumps into next booking page.
> Not exactly how I wanted having the validation in booking page though.

**models.py**

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'Employees'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    code = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.code}')"


class Book(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'Booking'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    choice = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Book('{self.username}, '{self.choice}')"
```

**forms.py**

```
    class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
        username = StringField('Name', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])
        code = StringField('Code', validators=[DataRequired()])
        submit = SubmitField('Book time')

        def validate_username(self, username):
            user = Book.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
            if user:
                raise ValidationError('You have registered your car today')
    
    class BookingForm(FlaskForm):
        book = RadioField('Label', choices=[('Station_1_morning', '07:00-11:00'), ('Station_1_afternoon', '11:00-15:00'),
                                            ('Station_2_morning', '07:00-11:00'), ('Station_2_afternoon', '11:00-15:00'),
                                            ('Station_3_morning', '07:00-11:00'), ('Station_3_afternoon', '11:00-15:00')],
                          coerce=str, validators=[InputRequired()])
        submit = SubmitField('Register time')
```

**routes.py**

```
@app.route("/booking", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def booking():
    session.permanent = True
    app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(seconds=5)
    form = BookingForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        book = Book(username=current_user.username, choice=form.book.data)
        db.session.add(book)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your time is registered', 'success')
    return render_template('booking.html', title='Booking', form=form)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the error. You could add a `print (user)` in the validation function to see what's in there.

Anyway this is still open to a race condition: if the same user books in another request between the check ("validation")and the commit. As a general rule, I'd rather try to commit and catch the integrity error. It can be a bit tricky to build a meaningful message from an integrity error exception object (I mean get the name of the offending field(s) from the object). Of course if you know for sure only one constraint applies, you may hardcode the message.

Comment: Thanks, I re-wrote the routes.py having a validation error directly in it

Comment: I don't see any edit in your question.

Comment: actually that didnt work having it directly in routes.py but i put it into `LoginForm` with extra `def validate_username`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question with your changes otherwise it is hard to answer anything relevant. (The point is not only to solve your case but to ensure the Q/A is useful for future readers.)

Comment: _Yes i did a change in code for `forms.py`

Comment: I edited my question to remove the first paragraphs because I realized some of the magic is hidden in FlaskForm (from WTF, I suppose), which makes the question a bit hard to understand at first sight. You should at least add a flask-WTF tag and perhaps mention it in the question. At this point, my answer is not very useful. I still think the approach I propose is better but I can't give you much more than that advice about how to debug.

Comment: My initial thoughts were to flash the error message in the BookingForm instead of LoginForm but I couldn’t figure out how to do that. I wanted that the user who already booked one choice from RadioField can still login into BookingForm but when he/she tries to book again another choice the error message pops up  telling that he/she has been already registered. In the code above that user just cannot login to be redirected to BookingForm